# Is this the correct OCV method to transform two 2D points to one 3D?

Tags: calibration, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's a moving object whose imagePoints I identity at two times with two MS LifeCams on my Windows 7 PC in MSVSC++.  I want to determine the distance between those two 3D points.  The steps I'm using are shown.  I included almost no detail since now I want to just learn if I'm using the right OpenCV 2.3.1 functions.

1. calibrateCamera for each camera

   ```
      output: cameraMatrix and distCoeffs for each camera
   ```
2. simpleBlobDetect once for each camera at two times

   ```
      output: point 1 (cam1x1, cam1y1) (cam2x1, cam2y1)
      output: point 2 (cam1x2, cam1y2) (cam2x2, cam2y2)
   ```
3. stereoCalibrate

   ```
      output: R, T, E, & F
   ```
4. stereoRectify

   ```
      this doesn't actually rectify any images but produces R1,R2,P1 & P2 so it can be done
   ```
5. undistortPoints

   ```
      output: vector of Point2f objects in rectified image
   ```
6. perspectiveTransform

   ```
    output: vector of Point3f objects
   ```

From 30k feet are these the correct steps?

Thanks.
Charles

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33615/is-this-the-correct-ocv-method-to-transform-two-2d-points-to-one-3d?/) by [Cherry 3.14](https://answers.ros.org/users/1622/cherry-3.14/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2012-05-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yep, sounds about right. But keep in mind that the camera calibration needs to be performed only once (if the stereo rig is fixed). So the order of the steps would be something like:

Only once (actually there is a ROS package that can help you: [camera_calibration](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera_calibration)):

1. calibrateCamera for each camera.
2. stereoCalibrate.
3. stereoRectify.
4. Store calibration parameters.

Later in your ros node:

1. Load calibration parameters.
2. On each iteration: simpleBlobDetect -> undistortPoints -> perspectiveTransform

Have fun!

---

Originally posted by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) with karma: 5625 on 2012-05-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0